# How can I get the current user name and picture in XMPP?

Tags: android, xmpp

I have a big problem on how to get the name of the current user in xmpp even the picture. I already used the AccountManager but I received null. Please help me to solve this problem. Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

If you are connected using XMPPConnection, you can use `getUser()` method to get the current logged in User Name.

For getting Profile Picture of Logged in user you have to use VCard to get the details of user,

```
VCard vCard = new VCard();
ProviderManager.getInstance().addIQProvider("vCard", "vcard-temp",
                                                         new VCardProvider());
vCard.load(connection_instance, logged_in_user_name);
byte[] bs = vCard.getAvatar();
```

Then you can get Bitmap from byte[] bs.

Comment: do you mean connection.getuser()?

Comment: what i get is username@chat.facebook.com/Smack_6758ff42_4C53E7FBCAE1D? is this the user name that i will be going to used in v
C